# View in class library - solution explorer show error but compiles without problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, class-library

After a lot of difficulties I managed to get my razor views to build, and IntelliSense to work properly in my C# class library but I'm running into an other problem, more bothering than really blocking.
The solution explorer always highlights my razor file with the following message : [image: Error message]

I do not understand why VisualStudio gives me these errors while the libraris are properly referenced and used everywhere in the project ...

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this problem ?

note: there is a Web.config even though it's a class library to enable the InteliSense.

edit: I have tried cleaning & rebuilding and restarting VS. The errors stayed.

Comment: Sometimes some errors/warnings stay although they have been resolved. Cleaning the solution and restarting VS often solves such problems.

Comment: I already tried, didn't work :-( thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems i have found a solution.

I had to copy and paste all the .dll that are in the subfolders of `path/to/solution/packages` right into my bin folder (note: if your build option targets the debug directory, paste them in the debug folder I think)

I also looked for `System.Web` globally because VS was still complaining about it after that. It was located in an IIS installation folder I believe. I copy/pasted it into my bin folder too and VS stopped complaining.

After that I restarted VisualStudio, it seems to be working.

This is not as clean as I wish I could have made it but it seems to be working ... The big problem now is that every time I clean the solution I have to copy/paste all these .dll again

If anyone has a better solution i'd be too happy to get it